# Kerberos with websphere NPE

Tags: websphere, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to setup Kerberos web authentication on Websphere (8.5.5). I have done my setup but when i try to access the login url i get the following NPE

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Initializer]: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoFilterConfig.doClientModule(SpnegoFilterConfig.java:179)
at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoFilterConfig.<init>(SpnegoFilterConfig.java:138)
at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoFilterConfig.getInstance(SpnegoFilterConfig.java:314)
at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.init(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:193)
```

I don't understand the error, or how to fix it. 
Thanks

UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app id="WebApp_1431678248278" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>warname_war</display-name>

<description>ApplicationDescription</description>

<!--Servlets-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.subpackage.Initializer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>initFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/init.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>initModule</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/init-module.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>initAuthentication</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/init-authentication.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>WindowOnSuccessCloseTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>500</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreateSecurityDb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.subpackage.CreateSecurityDatabaseServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>initFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/init.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>initAuthentication</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/init-authentication.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>sqlScriptsFolder</param-name>
        <param-value>/sql</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Data Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.subpackage.web.webmethod.DataServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logger</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.subpackage.context.DataServletImpl</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Status</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.subpackage.healthcheck.HealthCheckServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!--Servlet mappings-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Data Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dataService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logger</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logger</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Status</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/status</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreateSecurityDb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/createSecurityDatabase</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--Filters-->
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFormFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.package.otherpackage.authentication.UnifiedLoginFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>factoryName</param-name>
        <param-value>SSOAuthenticator</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>servletType</param-name>
        <param-value>webHtml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>useCaching</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>LogoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.package.otherpackage.authentication.impl.logic.filter.UnifiedLogoutFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>factoryName</param-name>
        <param-value>SSOAuthenticator</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.package.subpackage.utils.ResourceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>InitDbConFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.package.subpackage.webmethod.InitDbConnectionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!--Filter Mappings-->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>InitDbConFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFormFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>InitDbConFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Data Service</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFormFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Data Service</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LogoutFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/plugins/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/lib/atf/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--location to prevent users from listing some resources-->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/main</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.package.subpackage.context.TCSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<application-policy name="spnego-client">
```

This is my web.xml file

Comment: looks like you are using http://spnego.sourceforge.net/index.html. Could you please add the config you have in web.xml based on http://sourceforge.net/p/spnego/discussion/1003769/thread/31ca4a3d/ there could be missing input paramter
In addition you could as well check the build in SPNEGO support of WebSphere https://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP101065

Comment: Updated with my web.xml config

Comment: Debugging the application is seems that it tries to load some config from wsjaas.conf, this is some generated file found my Websphere profile. In this file there is no spnego-client configured, and the result is the above NPE

Comment: If i add 
spnego-client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};
spnego-server {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
storeKey=true;
}; to the wsjaas.conf file the NPE is gone, and i get 
IWAE0006E Archive is not a valid EAR File because the deployment descriptor can not be found (case sensitive): META-INF/application.xml
in logs\ffdc\

Comment: WebSphere supports Spnego, I'd suggest you to consider configuring Spnego authentication provided by the server instead of some third party.

Comment: I believe this is what i am trying to do.

Comment: @user3249353 You are trying to do something, hard to tell what exactly. You don't need any sourceforge libraries nor changes in wsjaas.conf. Here is link to infocenter http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_config.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-21-2-0&lang=en. When you enable SPNEGO application just needs to have Java EE security enabled to use that authentication, no custom filter is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i was getting the NPE is that by default websphere uses the wsjaas.conf file. You can change this by editing a system launch properties file /AppServer/properties/systemlaunch/base/.systemlaunch.properties.

There you have configured the java.security.auth.login.config
In the default wsjaas.conf there was a missing entry ("spnego-client") that the spnego API expects.